# multiplying by a constant on google sheets/excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

Here at work we have items that we sell to guests and each have a different price. 
I am trying to see if there is code/formula where I type in a quantity of an item sold and it auto-multiply by the price of the item and get a result in the cell where i typed in the quantity.

In my situation I have a already have the price on sheet1 cell c4. I would like to be able to type in a quantity on sheet2 cell D6 and it auto-multiply with sheet1 cell c4 and show the result on cell D6.

Comment: Please, try providing an example of what you're trying to achieve. As it is now, it's quite hard to understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Put this together, all on one sheet but you can move the data array easily.

[image]

As you select the product you are working with in cell D2 (data validation), then enter the quantity in cell F2 (again you can use data validation to control the range of numbers here), the calculation uses vlookup to get the correct price and multiply by quantity.